# which th best RASA NLU or SNIPS NLU?

Tags: nlp, rasa-nlu, snips, nlu

I would like to know the difference between **Snips NLU** and **Rasa NLU** ? 
which is simpler and powerful ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From an NLU standpoint, according to the [benchmark](https://medium.com/snips-ai/snips-nlu-is-an-open-source-private-by-design-alternative-to-dialogflow-amazon-lex-and-other-nlu-a95dbe16f4a1) published by Snips CTO, snips_nlu and rasa_nlu (with Spacy under the hood) have very good and almost identical performance.

As of today Rasa is probably a better choice if you care about any of the following items:

- **readiness to use**: Rasa core provides a drop-in replacement for common cloud solutions. It takes minutes to spin you own server on localhost, using either a model trained via rasa or downloaded from the service you want to replace.
- **language variety**: Snips currently supports [six languages](https://snips-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/languages.html), whereas Rasa [nine](https://nlu.rasa.com/languages.html). However some languages are only present in Snips, so it really boils down to your current need.

If these items don't make any difference to you, you're in a great spot: my suggestion is to prepare your dataset with [Chatito](https://rodrigopivi.github.io/Chatito/) and test by yourself which of the two libraries learns your specific data best.

Comment: https://github.com/snipsco/snips-nlu/raw/develop/.img/benchmarks.png

Comment: https://github.com/snipsco/snips-nlu